# "ORA-14400: inserted partition key doesn't map to any partition" even thought a range interval N is set up on the table

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, database-partitioning

I have an Oracle DB with version 19c (19.0.0.0.0). And I get the error "SQL Error [14400][72000]: ORA-14400: inserted partition key doesn't map to any partition" even thought a range interval N is set up on the table.

I use the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE BAISMART.GSWBIF_IFRS_TEST_MARS3035
(
  GSWBIF_ID          NUMBER,
  MODUL              CHAR(2 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
  KDNRH              NUMBER(14)                 NOT NULL,
  KTONR              NUMBER(10)                 NOT NULL,
  GSREF              VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)          NOT NULL,
  EWBBT              NUMBER(18,2)               NOT NULL,
  EWBWH              CHAR(3 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
  EWBBP              NUMBER(18,2)               NOT NULL,
  EWBWP              CHAR(3 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
  ABSBT              NUMBER(18,2)               NOT NULL,
  ABTYP              CHAR(1 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
  EWBBS              NUMBER(18,2)               NOT NULL,
  EWBWS              CHAR(3 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
  RSTBT              NUMBER(18,2)               DEFAULT 0                     NOT NULL,
  RSTWH              CHAR(3 BYTE)               DEFAULT ' '                   NOT NULL,
  ABSWH              CHAR(3 BYTE)               DEFAULT 'EUR'                 NOT NULL,
  DXIFD              NUMBER(8),
  IFNAM              CHAR(10 BYTE)              NOT NULL,
  BPLO_ID            NUMBER(10)                 NOT NULL,
  MAP_RUN_ID_INSERT  NUMBER(22)                 NOT NULL,
  MAP_RUN_ID_UPDATE  NUMBER(22),
  MDANT              CHAR(3 BYTE)               DEFAULT '100'
)
COLUMN STORE COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH ROW LEVEL LOCKING
TABLESPACE BAIS_DATA
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
PARTITION BY RANGE (BPLO_ID) INTERVAL(1)
SUBPARTITION BY LIST (IFNAM, MODUL)
SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE (
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CB_N1_K1 VALUES (('CB        ', 'N1'),('CB        ', 'K1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CB_EC VALUES (('CB        ', 'EC')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CB_G1 VALUES (('CB        ', 'G1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CB_A1 VALUES (('CB        ', 'A1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CB_S1 VALUES (('CB        ', 'S1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CB_AK VALUES (('CB        ', 'AK')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CB_ZU VALUES (('CB        ', 'ZU')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_INGAT_N1_K1 VALUES (('INGAT     ', 'N1'),('INGAT     ', 'K1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_INGAT_G1_EC VALUES (('INGAT     ', 'G1'),('INGAT     ', 'EC')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_INGAT_A1 VALUES (('INGAT     ', 'A1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_INGAT_S1 VALUES (('INGAT     ', 'S1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_INGAT_AK VALUES (('INGAT     ', 'AK')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_INGAT_ZU VALUES (('INGAT     ', 'ZU')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_LOANIQ_N1_K1 VALUES (('LOANIQ    ', 'N1'),('LOANIQ    ', 'K1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_LOANIQ_G1_EC VALUES (('LOANIQ    ', 'G1'),('LOANIQ    ', 'EC')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_LOANIQ_A1 VALUES (('LOANIQ    ', 'A1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_LOANIQ_S1 VALUES (('LOANIQ    ', 'S1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_LOANIQ_AK VALUES (('LOANIQ    ', 'AK')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_LOANIQ_ZU VALUES (('LOANIQ    ', 'ZU')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_VORTEXCB_N1_K1 VALUES (('VORTEXCB  ', 'N1'),('VORTEXCB  ', 'K1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_VORTEXCB_G1_EC VALUES (('VORTEXCB  ', 'G1'),('VORTEXCB  ', 'EC')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_VORTEXCB_A1 VALUES (('VORTEXCB  ', 'A1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_VORTEXCB_S1 VALUES (('VORTEXCB  ', 'S1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_VORTEXCB_AK VALUES (('VORTEXCB  ', 'AK')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_VORTEXCB_ZU VALUES (('VORTEXCB  ', 'ZU')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CBAT_N1_K1 VALUES (('CBAT      ', 'N1'),('CBAT      ', 'K1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CBAT_G1 VALUES (('CBAT      ', 'G1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CBAT_EC VALUES (('CBAT      ', 'EC')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CBAT_A1 VALUES (('CBAT      ', 'A1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CBAT_S1 VALUES (('CBAT      ', 'S1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CBAT_AK VALUES (('CBAT      ', 'AK')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_CBAT_ZU VALUES (('CBAT      ', 'ZU')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_KORDOBA_N1_K1 VALUES (('KORDOBA   ', 'N1'),('KORDOBA   ', 'K1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_KORDOBA_G1_EC VALUES (('KORDOBA   ', 'G1'),('KORDOBA   ', 'EC')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_KORDOBA_A1 VALUES (('KORDOBA   ', 'A1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_KORDOBA_S1 VALUES (('KORDOBA   ', 'S1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_KORDOBA_AK VALUES (('KORDOBA   ', 'AK')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_KORDOBA_ZU VALUES (('KORDOBA   ', 'ZU')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_EQUENS_WL_N1_K1 VALUES (('EQUENS-WL ', 'N1'),('EQUENS-WL ', 'K1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_EQUENS_WL_G1_EC VALUES (('EQUENS-WL ', 'G1'),('EQUENS-WL ', 'EC')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_EQUENS_WL_A1 VALUES (('EQUENS-WL ', 'A1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_EQUENS_WL_S1 VALUES (('EQUENS-WL ', 'S1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_EQUENS_WL_AK VALUES (('EQUENS-WL ', 'AK')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_EQUENS_WL_ZU VALUES (('EQUENS-WL ', 'ZU')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_PROFILE7_N1_K1 VALUES (('PROFILE7  ', 'N1'),('PROFILE7  ', 'K1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_PROFILE7_G1_EC VALUES (('PROFILE7  ', 'G1'),('PROFILE7  ', 'EC')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_PROFILE7_A1 VALUES (('PROFILE7  ', 'A1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_PROFILE7_S1 VALUES (('PROFILE7  ', 'S1')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_PROFILE7_AK VALUES (('PROFILE7  ', 'AK')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_PROFILE7_ZU VALUES (('PROFILE7  ', 'ZU')),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_KORDOBA VALUES (
    ('KORDOBA-BF', 'N1'),
    ('KORDOBA-BF', 'G1'),
    ('KORDOBA-BF', 'A1'),
    ('KORDOBA-BF', 'S1'),
    ('KORDOBA-BF', 'AK'),
    ('KORDOBA-BF', 'ZU'),
    ('KORDOBA-BF', 'K1'),
    ('KORDOBA-BF', 'EC'),
    ('KORDOBA-PK', 'N1'),
    ('KORDOBA-PK', 'G1'),
    ('KORDOBA-PK', 'A1'),
    ('KORDOBA-PK', 'S1'),
    ('KORDOBA-PK', 'AK'),
    ('KORDOBA-PK', 'ZU'),
    ('KORDOBA-PK', 'K1'),
    ('KORDOBA-PK', 'EC'),
    ('KORDOBA-RK', 'N1'),
    ('KORDOBA-RK', 'G1'),
    ('KORDOBA-RK', 'A1'),
    ('KORDOBA-RK', 'S1'),
    ('KORDOBA-RK', 'AK'),
    ('KORDOBA-RK', 'ZU'),
    ('KORDOBA-RK', 'K1'),
    ('KORDOBA-RK', 'EC'),
    ('KORDOBA-GK', 'N1'),
    ('KORDOBA-GK', 'G1'),
    ('KORDOBA-GK', 'A1'),
    ('KORDOBA-GK', 'S1'),
    ('KORDOBA-GK', 'AK'),
    ('KORDOBA-GK', 'ZU'),
    ('KORDOBA-GK', 'K1'),
    ('KORDOBA-GK', 'EC'),
    ('KORDOBA-TH', 'N1'),
    ('KORDOBA-TH', 'G1'),
    ('KORDOBA-TH', 'A1'),
    ('KORDOBA-TH', 'S1'),
    ('KORDOBA-TH', 'AK'),
    ('KORDOBA-TH', 'ZU'),
    ('KORDOBA-TH', 'K1'),
    ('KORDOBA-TH', 'EC')
),
SUBPARTITION SYS_SUB_DEF VALUES (DEFAULT) )
(
    PARTITION SYS_P2064940 VALUES LESS THAN (20190431) COLUMN STORE COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH ROW LEVEL LOCKING TABLESPACE BAIS_DATA
        PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE (MAXSIZE UNLIMITED BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT )
);


ALTER TABLE BAISMART.GSWBIF_IFRS_TEST_MARS3035 ADD (
  CONSTRAINT UK_GSWBIF_IFRS_TEST_MARS3035__I
  UNIQUE (MODUL, KDNRH, KTONR, GSREF, BPLO_ID, IFNAM, MDANT)
  USING INDEX LOCAL
  ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

And I make the following insert:

```
Insert into BAISMART.GSWBIF_IFRS_TEST_MARS3035
   (MODUL, KDNRH, KTONR, GSREF, EWBBT, 
    EWBWH, EWBBP, EWBWP, ABSBT, ABTYP, 
    EWBBS, EWBWS, RSTBT, RSTWH, ABSWH, 
    DXIFD, IFNAM, BPLO_ID, MAP_RUN_ID_INSERT, MDANT)
 Values
   ('ZU', 7701810149, 0, '000301NEARTNALON', 3.31, 
    'EUR', 0, '   ', 0, ' ', 
    3.31, 'EUR', 0, '   ', '   ', 
    20210731, 'CB        ', 20210731, 269494, '100');
```

After that I get the error ORA-14400.

But when I shift the date in of the initial partition to a later date like

```
PARTITION SYS_P2064940 VALUES LESS THAN (20190431) COLUMN STORE COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH ROW LEVEL LOCKING TABLESPACE BAIS_DATA
    PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE (MAXSIZE UNLIMITED BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
```

it works.

Are there any limites?
I have seen that [there are some logical limits on partitions number](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/logical-database-limits.html). But on the insert mentioned upper in the question DB creates only one additional partition independently on which date I specify, so that shouldn't be a problem, am I wrong? Maybe there are any other limits that I didn't notice?

Comment: Do you really work with values like `'CB        '`? Maybe better use `IFNAM VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)` instead of `CHAR` data type. And using number (or even string) data type for `DATE` values is usually also bad design.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I absolutely agree with you, if I had a chance I would redesign not only the table, but the whole data model :D  But I cannot ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max number of (sub-)partitions does not apply to the real number of (sub-)partitions. The limit applies to the theoretical number based on existing min and max value, i.e. gaps are taken into consideration.

As already mentioned in my commend you should **never** store date values as number (or string), it's a design flaw. Use always proper `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type.

`20210731 - 20190431 = 20'300` - not 823 days. Each of your partition has 52 subpartitions. `20'300 x 52 = 1'055'600` which exceeds the limit of 1024K - 1 = 1'023'999 subpartitions

Apart from that `20190431` may represent 31st of April, which does not exist.

You see, there are several reasons to use proper data types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the limit 1024K - 1 means I can have 1023999 partitions, right?

Comment: thanks for the answer! I thought that subpartitions are not counted in.